# Spring MVC @ExceptionHandler chaining

Tags: spring-mvc, exception

Is there a way to chain @ExceptionHandler with exception throwing?
I'm trying to wrap exceptions throw in request handler methods before sending a response:

```
@ExceptionHandler(value = JsonParseException.class)
public void handleJsonParseException(JsonParseException e) throws BadRequestException {
    throw new BadRequestException(e);
}

@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
@ExceptionHandler(value = BadRequestException.class)
public @ResponseBody RestResponse handleBadRequest(BadRequestException e) {
    log.info("Bad REST Request", e);
    return constructErrorResponse(e);
}
```

So, I'd like to for the `handleBadRequest()` to catch BadRequestException re-thrown from `handleJsonParseException()`.

With the code above, `handleJsonParseException()` causes server to return default error page instead of `RestResponse`.

Is this possible or will I have to put exception wrapping in request handlers' try - catch?

Answer (score 1):

Is not possible:

- [Chained Annotated Exception Handling - @ExceptionHandler](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13726) (**SPR-13726**)